# How to access the chips name and id added dynamically from a chipgroup in android?

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-chips

I have added chips dynamically from a chipgroup, so that when a user selects item from a list then these chips get added in the chipgroup. Now the problem is that how to gain the name of each chips in the chipgroup?

This `setTag(String tagName)` method gets called when a user clicks on an item from a listview. And then the item gets converted into chips in the chipgroup field.

```
private void setTag(String tagName)
{
    final Chip chip = new Chip(activity);
    int paddingDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    chip.setPadding(paddingDp, paddingDp, paddingDp, paddingDp);
    chip.setChecked(true);
    chip.setText(tagName);
    chip.setCloseIconResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp);
    chip.setCloseIconEnabled(true);
    // Added click listener on close icon to remove tag from ChipGroup
    chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chipGroup.removeView(chip);
        }
    });
    chipGroup.addView(chip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<chipGroup.getChildCount();i++){
      Chip chip = (Chip)chipGroup.getChildAt(i);
      String chipText = chip.getText();
      // Do something
}
```